# Excel formula for conversion of string to time

Tags: excel, string, math, time

The format of string is `00h 24m`.

We tried to use

```
    = TIMEVALUE(B1)
```

and it was not able to convert to Time format.

Comment: Try `=TIMEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B1,"h ",":"),"m",""))`

Comment: Yes, it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace `h`+space with `:` and remove `m` to adjust the string for the `TIMEVALUE` formula.

Use

```
=TIMEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(I9,"h ",":"),"m",""))
```

[image]

FYI, see the [`TIMEVALUE` help](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TIMEVALUE-function-0b615c12-33d8-4431-bf3d-f3eb6d186645):

> The TIMEVALUE function syntax has the following arguments:
>
> **Time_text**    Required. A text string that represents a time in any one of the Microsoft Excel time formats; for example, "6:45 PM" and "18:45" text strings within quotation marks that represent time.